# Nested polygons empty the filling of outer polygon

Tags: paperjs

With the help of paper.js: Is it possible to create two polygons that lie on top of each other whereas one makes the color of the other transparent? Please see the image below as it makes the question more understandable.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use [`CompoundPath`](http://paperjs.org/reference/compoundpath/#compoundpath-pathData) to create complex shapes with holes. 
[Here is an example](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.4/S/rZHBbsMgDIZfxeKSRIoqqq4Xqp3yAlN3bHqg4C0o1ESEtIcq7z6jtN163y+QwHzG5ucmSJ9RKPHZYzKdqIUJNu8vOsKgUwfvQHiFJpyHMJH94FB5awlYpnPeRiQFhyWQleEMrRoXjccH+5BBShjVggVHqdzKGrayql+5qK2bRgUb+Ruf/0L/XGf9UmdZH+/sl/O+CT7wdcXJa9MX94MRPZqEVkGKE7Y0V7uWsmkrbW2T3Smfbe6Z1PTNnXIfPN54rqWsnim5yn7yyIYXeEEK1hY7/o9TRN0P+QmjUIfj/AM=).